# How to set up Ubuntu Mate for suspension after inactivity?

Tags: 20.04, power-management, ubuntu-mate

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 20.04. In the settings, there is the option of putting the computer to sleep after inactivity, but not to suspend it (and putting it to sleep uses considerably more battery). Is there a way to make it suspend after an amount of idle time?

Comment: Sleep is suspend - see https://guide.ubuntu-mate.org/#personalization-power .

Comment: It just isn't. If I let it sleep it uses much more battery than if I suspend it manually. Furthermore, the automatic "sleep" doesn't even lead to blinking of the ON button, while suspending does lead to such blinking.

Comment: This may be caused bad ACPI specification of yours laptop/computer. Also try to ask on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ .

Comment: would you mind to give details about the Ubuntu Mate 20.04 settings? Where (menu) did you find those settings? I am after to disable inactivity completely